# Setting up a role and linking it to an user is not working as expected in SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, privileges, oracle-xe, oracle21c

I created a role `R_CLIENTE`:

```
CREATE ROLE R_CLIENTE IDENTIFIED BY RolCliente;
```

Then I granted some privileges on it:

```
GRANT SELECT ON alquiler.CLIENTE TO R_CLIENTE;
```

(Schema `alquiler` and table `CLIENTE` already exist). Then I created an user `U_Cliente1`:

```
CREATE USER U_Cliente1 IDENTIFIED BY Cliente1 DEFAULT TABLESPACE table_def TEMPORARY TABLESPACE table_temp QUOTA 2M ON table_def PASSWORD EXPIRE;
```

(Both tablespaces already exist). I granted `U_Cliente1` to `R_CLIENTE` privileges:

```
GRANT R_CLIENTE TO U_Cliente1;
```

When I login as `U_Cliente1` I am not able to select any data from the table alquiler.CLIENTE:

```
SQL> desc alquiler.CLIENTE;
ERROR:
ORA-04043: object alquiler.CLIENTE does not exist
```

However, if I grant directly the privilege to the user `U_Cliente1`:

```
GRANT SELECT ON alquiler.CLIENTE TO U_Cliente1;
```

Now I am able to select the table `alquiler.CLIENTE`:

```
SQL> desc alquiler.CLIENTE;
 Name                      Null?    Type
 ----------------------------------------- -------- ----------------------------
 K_CODCLIENTE                  NOT NULL NUMBER(5)
 N_NOMBRE1                 NOT NULL VARCHAR2(15)
 N_NOMBRE2                      VARCHAR2(15)
 N_APELLIDO1                   NOT NULL VARCHAR2(15)
 N_APELLIDO2                        VARCHAR2(15)
 N_DIRECCION                   NOT NULL VARCHAR2(50)
 Q_TELEFONO                NOT NULL NUMBER(10)
 K_CODREF                       NUMBER(5)
 I_TIPOID                  NOT NULL VARCHAR2(2)
 Q_IDENTIFICACION              NOT NULL VARCHAR2(10)
```

How can I properly link a role and user(s) so they can all share the same privileges?

Answer (score 0):

The reason that the direct grant worked the way it did is because direct grants are always active. Roles can be activated and deactivated within a session. In your example you didn't configure the role as a *default* role, so it must be explicitly activated after you login, like [this](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/SET-ROLE.html#GUID-863F9B6F-82B4-4C49-8E3A-3BA33AE79CAB):

```
set role r_cliente;
```

alternatively, after granting the role set it as a default for the user:

```
alter user U_Cliente1 default role r_cliente;
```

or

```
alter user U_Cliente1 default role all;
```

Then the role will be active automatically when you login.

Comment: Why do I get an ORA-01031: insufficient privileges error when trying to ```alter user U_Cliente1 default role all;``` after ```set role r_cliente;```?

Comment: `set role r_cliente` will disable any other roles. you should only do that if you haven't already set a default.

Comment: So, I should just type ```alter user U_Cliente1 default role all;``` and the role will be assigned automatically to the user?

Comment: first `grant` the role, then `alter user` to make the role a default role, then login as the user (role changes only take effect on next login).